# Add property to image loading function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using "Rocket Lazy Load" plugin to lazy loading my images but it is incompatible with sliders. In the plugin page in wordpress.org, is said: `you should add 'data-no-lazy="1"' property to your image tag then it won't be effected`. My picture calling function is:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-blog-featured', array('title' => "")); ?>
```

How can I add the mentioned property to my slider images?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, you can add attribute like below:

```
 the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail-blog-featured', array( 'title' => get_the_title(),
    'data-no-lazy' => '1' ) );
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why it's not working. In the final html, no sign of that and the plugin do the job.

Comment: I forgot to say I use a plugin for external feature images. It's that replacing the attributes. Any thought on that? How can I solve it?